# Reclassify with attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, fields-attributes, raster-calculator, reclassify

So, I don't really know how to word what I want to ask, but I took a DEM file and did used the raster calculator to select a certain elevation range. After that I reclassified it to separate  it into different levels of elevation.

[image]

How do I get the new reclassified layer to have attribute data of those levels of elevation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reclassify Tool will convert your raster into a format which allows for Attributes to be added to the Raster itself.

If i have understood your question, you are looking to add the elevation ranges to the attribute table so that you can use this information in perhaps the legend of a description of what the newly reclassified values mean.

Right-click the reclassified raster and you will see the "Open Attribute Table", alternatively you can hold the "CTRL" key and double click the layer in the ToC.

Add a field and call it "Range", make it text.
You can either start editing and manually change each of the ranges t othe description you want...or...
You can create a table containing the reclassified value and the description you want, and then perform a table join between the table and raster - using the reclassified values as the linking field. You can then copy the joined data into the field you just created.